# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZXingWidgetController", referenced from: objc-class-ref in RootViewController.o using Zxing

Tags: iphone, ios, zxing, armv7

I am incorporating qrcode reader from Zxing in my app. I tested the scantest which was there in Zxing before in Xcode4.5 and it working well. I updated the iOS sdk to 6.1 and updated Xcode to 4.6 now this one is showing error. First it was showing error for gcc compiler and its resolved now and now its showing error for

`"Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s"`

P.S:- After reading many solutions, I tried changing few things like all architecture set to same(Scantest, ZxingWidget, ZxingTouch), Changed the compiler to LLVM GCC 4.2, set other warning flags to -Werror etc.

Special issue is the build is working for the iphone simulator 6.1.

Comment: you have asked 15 question but have not accepted any answer even if your problem is solved.

Comment: @CRDave, actually I dont know how to accept an answer. I am very sorry for that. Please let me know the procedure.

Comment: visit this two page so you get some good basic of SO: http://stackoverflow.com/about http://stackoverflow.com/faq. You are alwayes welcome for help

Answer (score 3):

If you are using any lib file then check for Build phases->Link binary with Libraries and check if respective lib is included or not.

If you are using source files then check if.m files are added to current target.

Thanks,
Jim.

Comment: Thats correct @Jim and I checked for library libZXingWidget.a is there  
however the .m file for the respected error that is ZxingWidgetController and QRCodeReader is not listed in compile sources, however ther are included in the Zxing xcode project.

Comment: I added them my friend however as they are the part of Zxing Library and the test project have dependancy on the library so when I added those two file in compile sources ..many other error arrises. so thats not the issue I think.

Comment: If you are using source files then even though you have used one/two files, other dependent files must be included your target.

Comment: no probs...I solved it by building a new project and integrating Zxing into it. The integrated ScanTest of Zxing is not working well, it has many issues working with different compiler and architecture...We should report that. Thanx everyone for helping me to go through.